# ASP.NET MVC/EF Code First error: Unable to retrieve metadata for model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I'm trying to create a controller in MVC4 and I'm getting an error I don't understand (I'm new to MVC).  It says "Unable to retrieve metadata for 'CIT.ViewModels.DashboardViewModel'..." and then gives 2 possible problems.  One is that the DashboardViewModel has no key defined.  The other is that EntitySet 'DashboardViewModels' has no key defined.

I defined a key for DashboardViewModel, but that didn't solve the problem.  Here is my DashboardViewModel;

```
public class DashboardViewModel
    {

        public DashboardViewModel() { }

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Hardware Hardware { get; set; }
        public Software Software { get; set; }
        public HardwareType HardwareType { get; set; }
        public Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
        public SoftwarePublisher SoftwarePublisher { get; set; }


    }
```

As you can see it is composed of classes.  I did this so I could have multiple classes accessible from the same view.  I didn't think it needed a key, but I added one and that didn't fix the problem.  The other error sounded like it was looking for a DbSet for DashboardViewModels.  As I understand it, your DbSets are your tables.  I don't want or need a DashboardViewModels table.  I'm only doing that so I can have multiple tables/classes accessible in my view.  That's working fine up to this point.

When I am trying to create the controller, I am using the DashboardViewModel as as my model and Context as my context.  Here is my context:

```
public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Software> Softwares { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Location> Locations { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SoftwarePublisher> SoftwarePublishers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SoftwareType> SoftwareTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Hardware> Hardwares { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Manufacturer> Manufacturers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<HardwareType> HardwareTypes { get; set; }
 }
```

How do I address these errors?

Comment: post your controller code.  EF shouldn't care about your view model in any way.

Comment: I can't create the controller because of the error.  That's the problem.

Comment: I think you are confused between Views and Domain Entities. Your entities represent your database , while your views are just  abstractions of the entities (read database)

Comment: That's possible.  How do I address the error?